# Как вырезать из строки часть от символа до символа?

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо вырезать из строки скрипт, к примеру моя строка выглядит так:

```
<p>
<script>console.log('hello')</script>
<script>console.log('hello')</script>
</p>
<p>
<script>console.log('my name')</script>
</p>
```

Отсюда мне нужно получить три скрипта

```
<script>console.log('hello')</script>
<script>console.log('hello')</script>
<script>console.log('my name')</script>
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Вот что у меня получилось реализовать:

```
        let arr = Array.from(items.description?.matchAll(/<(.*?)>/g));
        console.log(arr)
        let mass = arr.filter(it => it.includes('script'))
        let result = mass[0].input.replace('<p>', '');
```

Как можно это реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: `str.match(/<script>.*?<\/script>/g).join('\n')`

Comment: Используйте полноценный парсер html. С помощью регулярных выражений это сделать невозможно.

Comment: Если что, то речь идёт про [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Отсюда мне нужно получить три скрипта.
> Как это можно реализовать?

Например вот так...

```js
const str = `<p>
<script>console.log('hello')<\/script>
<script>console.log('hello')<\/script>
<\/p>
<p>
<script>console.log('my name')<\/script>
<\/p>`
const o = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html")
const s = [...o.querySelectorAll('script')].map(o => o.outerHTML).join('\n')
console.log(s)
```

Или регуляркой

```js
const str = `<p>
<script>console.log('hello')<\/script>
<script>console.log('hello')<\/script>
<\/p>
<p>
<script>console.log('my name')<\/script>
<\/p>`
const re = /<script>.*?<\/script>/gi
let s = str.match(re).join('\n')
console.log(s)
```